# Turn off bold in title + change header on title page

Tags: header-footer, titles

I am trying to make a title page following a template provided.  I need to have a top right header on every page except the first where I should have only the name of the grant council at the top left (with no line below it this time).  I can see how to get the headers for all pages except the title page. I tried to follow [Header or footer of title page differs with that of main text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14653/header-or-footer-of-title-page-differs-with-that-of-main-text) to modify only the title page header but with no luck.  I also need a multi-line centred title. How can I turn off bold for some of the lines in the title?  Finally, I need to move the whole title up to the top of the page, that is remove much of the space above its top line.

Here is a skeleton version of the file I would like to get working.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

%Add header to each page
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{Name, Title, Section}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\usepackage{mathptmx}


\title{Name\\Grant\\Research proposal\\Part B\\Title\\Acronym\\Length}

\date{}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section*{test}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: Although it is the page with the title on it so a title page in that sense, I need to start the document directly below the title .

Comment: OK I think my edited solution works for your edited question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a personal preference, I would forego the use of `\maketitle` in favour of having a little more freedom in typesetting the different style of the title page and what follows. In that regard, consider the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\pagestyle{fancy}
% Global fancy header style
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{Name, Title, Section}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}

\begin{document}

% Set fancy header style for title page only (local fancy header style)
\fancypagestyle{titlepage}{
  \lhead{Name of Grant Council}% Grant name
  \rhead{}% Remove global (right) header 
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\thispagestyle{titlepage}

\begingroup
  \centering \Huge
  Name\\Grant\\Research proposal\\Part B\\Title\\Acronym\\Length\\
\endgroup

\section*{test}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}​
```

The "title" is typeset using `\centering\Huge`, so there's no **bold**. Headings are set for the first page under the fancy style `titlepage`, that modifies *only* the title page headings (via `\thispagestyle{titlepage}`) - that is, this is a local change. The [`lipsum` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) was included merely to populate the document with some dummy text.

[image: Title page with different heading]

Of course, spacing after the heading can be adjusted as required (using, say, `\bigskip` or other vertical spacing techniques).

Comment: Thanks. One issue is that it seems to need the \newpage otherwise the title page acquires the headers of the later pages (if you just delete the \newpage command you can see you never get the \lhead{Name of Grant Council} header). In my case I need to be able to start the document under the title, not on a new page (I have removed the \newpage from my MWE now).  How can I still get it to work?

Comment: @Raphael: Then you would need to define a heading style similar to what Seamus did and use it the form `\thispagestyle{...}`. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

I would say give up trying to use the `\title` command to do all the work and just place the elements yourself with judicious use of `\\[length]` to put vertical space between the elements and some explicit `\Huge,\large,\normalsize`-like commands to have the elements appear different sizes.

I've added the `titling` package to allow you to use `\thetitle` and `\theauthor` to print the title and author respectively.

EDIT: since you don't want the title to be on a separate page, removing the titlepage environment (but keeping its content) works perfectly

Here's a first stab at doing what you want:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

%Add header to each page
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{Name, Title, Section}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\fancypagestyle{titlepage}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \lhead{Grant info}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
  \setlength\headheight{1.5\baselineskip} % <-- set to whatever you need on the first page.
}
\usepackage{titling}

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\title{Name}
\author{A. Author}
\date{}
\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{titlepage}
  \begin{center}
    \Huge \theauthor \\[1cm]
    \Large Grant \\
    Research proposal\\[.5cm]
    \normalsize Part B \\
    \Huge \thetitle \\[1cm]
    \large Acronym \\
    length
  \end{center}

\section*{test}

\end{document}
```

Note I've used the `\fancypagestyle` to define a `titlepage` page style (as is done in the answer you linked to) and applied this to the title page.

For the record, the [`titlepage` environment](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation) which doesn't work for this particular problem, gives you more control over where to put the various elements of your page. This is definitely preferable to throwing it all into the `\title` command.

Comment: Thanks. Now I have two perfect answers and only one to accept.